# MFC Menu item 'window:windows' presents empty list despite open child windows

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm maintaining a aged c++ unmanaged MFC multiple-document program which is now using MFC version 10, compiled with MSVC 2010.

My problem is with the 'Window' menu.  When there are one or more child windows open, the windows appear in a list in the window menu, with the check mark next to the currently active window.  Underneath that is a menu item 'Windows...'.   When that is chosen, a dialog box appears with an empty list, no matter how many child windows are open.

I would like this to either work properly or if I cannot solve the problem, it may be acceptable to simply remove this menu item from the window menu.   However, I don't see any way to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that frame window for the children were not derived from CMDIChildWndEx. It was an easy change, and now my windows show up in the list of windows.